# Regex for finding valid sphinx fields

Tags: python, regex, django, sphinx

I'm trying to validate that the fields given to sphinx are valid, but I'm having difficulty.

Imagine that valid fields are cat, mouse, dog, puppy.

Valid searches would then be:

- @cat search terms
- @(cat) search terms
- @(cat, dog) search term
- @cat searchterm1 @dog searchterm2
- @(cat, dog) searchterm1 @mouse searchterm2

So, I want to use a regular expression to find terms such as cat, dog, mouse in the above examples, and check them against a list of valid terms.

Thus, a query such as:
@(goat)

Would produce an error because goat is not a valid term.

I've gotten so that I can find simple queries such as @cat with this regex: (?:@)([^( ]*)

But I can't figure out how to find the rest.

I'm using python & django, for what that's worth.

Comment: Why do you need to check this query with a regex? Isn't it possible to control the validity of the query when you build it? You hardly get low-level sphinx queries as an input, do you?

Comment: Actually, I'm allowing users to build their queries this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this a different way, since none of the above worked. First I found the fields like @cat, with this:

```
attributes = re.findall('(?:@)([^\( ]*)', query)
```

Next, I found the more complicated ones, with this:

```
regex0 = re.compile('''
    @               # at sign
    (?:             # start non-capturing group
        \w+             # non-whitespace, one or more
        \b              # a boundary character (i.e. no more \w)
        |               # OR
        (               # capturing group
            \(              # left paren
            [^@(),]+        # not an @(),
            (?:                 # another non-caputing group
                , *             # a comma, then some spaces
                [^@(),]+        # not @(),
            )*              # some quantity of this non-capturing group
            \)              # a right paren
        )               # end of non-capuring group
    )           # end of non-capturing group
    ''', re.VERBOSE)

# and this puts them into the attributes list.
groupedAttributes = re.findall(regex0, query)
for item in groupedAttributes:
    attributes.extend(item.strip("(").strip(")").split(", "))
```

Next, I checked if the attributes I found were valid, and added them (uniquely to an array):

```
# check if the values are valid.
validRegex = re.compile(r'^mice$|^mouse$|^cat$|^dog$')

# if they aren't add them to a new list.
badAttrs = []
for attribute in attributes:
    if len(attribute) == 0:
        # if it's a zero length attribute, we punt
        continue
    if validRegex.search(attribute.lower()) == None:
        # if the attribute from the search isn't in the valid list
        if attribute not in badAttrs:
            # and the attribute isn't already in the list
            badAttrs.append(attribute)
```

Thanks all for the help though. I'm very glad to have had it!

Answer (score 3):

To match all allowed fields, the following rather fearful looking regex works:

```
@((?:cat|mouse|dog|puppy)\b|\((?:(?:cat|mouse|dog|puppy)(?:, *|(?=\))))+\))
```

It returns these matches, in order: `@cat`, `@(cat)`, `@(cat, dog)`, `@cat`, `@dog`, `@(cat, dog)`, `@mouse`.

The regex breaks down as follows:

```
@                               # the literal character "@"
(                               # match group 1
  (?:cat|mouse|dog|puppy)       #  one of your valid search terms (not captured)
  \b                            #  a word boundary
  |                             #  or...
  \(                            #  a literal opening paren
  (?:                           #  non-capturing group
    (?:cat|mouse|dog|puppy)     #   one of your valid search terms (not captured)
    (?:                         #   non-capturing group
      , *                       #    a comma "," plus any number of spaces
      |                         #    or...
      (?=\))                    #    a position followed by a closing paren
    )                           #   end non-capture group
  )+                            #  end non-capture group, repeat
  \)                            #  a literal closing paren
)                               # end match group one.
```

Now to identify any *invalid* search, you would wrap all that in a negative look-ahead:

```
@(?!(?:cat|mouse|dog|puppy)\b|\((?:(?:cat|mouse|dog|puppy)(?:, *|(?=\))))+\))
--^^
```

This would identify any `@` character after which an invalid search term (or term combination) was attempted. Modifying it so that it also *matches* the invalid attempt instead of just pointing at it is not that hard anymore.

You would have to prepare `(?:cat|mouse|dog|puppy)` from your field dynamically and plug it into the static rest of the regex. Should not be too hard to do either.

Comment: This matches `@cat` in `@caterpillar`.

Comment: I tested this against this regex, @foo @Dog @cat @mouse foo,bar @(Dog, cat, mice) @(bar, mouse) @(mouse) (cat | dog), and it produced good results. I shall use it, thank you.

Comment: Although, now I see Tim's comment, and it seems to be true.

Comment: I was able to modify this so it doesn't have the @caterpillar problem: @((?:court|casename|docstatus|doctext)\b|\\((?:(?:court|casename|docstatus|doctext)(?:, |(?=\\))))+\\))

But it still has a problem because @(mouse, caterpillar, dog) fails to find anything. I also just applied the negative look-ahead, thinking it would return the invalid fields, but it didn't work either. 

I should emphasize: I need the INVALID terms, not the valid ones.

Comment: @mlissner: I told you so. ;-) "This would identify any @ character after which an invalid search term (or term combination) was attempted."

Comment: @Tim: Well spotted, you are correct. Easily fixed (as @mlissner pointed out as well) by adding a `\b`. Just fixed my answer.

Comment: @mlissner: Expanding the regex to include the actual invalid term involves a little brain work, but it is not hard. Take it as a challenge, I already did the hardest part. (Hint: The match already *is* at a position right in front of any invalid term, all you need to do is to go forward.)

Answer (score 2):

This pyparsing solution follows a similar logic path as your posted answer.  All tags are matched, and then checked against the list of known valid tags, removing them from the reported results.  Only those matches that have values left over after removing the valid ones are reported as matches.

```
from pyparsing import *

# define the pattern of a tag, setting internal results names for easy validation
AT,LPAR,RPAR = map(Suppress,"@()")
term = Word(alphas,alphanums).setResultsName("terms",listAllMatches=True)
sphxTerm = AT + ~White() + ( term | LPAR + delimitedList(term) + RPAR )

# define tags we consider to be valid
valid = set("cat mouse dog".split())

# define a parse action to filter out valid terms, and attach to the sphxTerm
def filterValid(tokens):
    tokens = [t for t in tokens.terms if t not in valid]
    if not(tokens):
        raise ParseException("",0,"")
    return tokens
sphxTerm.setParseAction(filterValid)


##### Test out the parser #####

test = """@cat search terms @ house
    @(cat) search terms 
    @(cat, dog) search term @(goat)
    @cat searchterm1 @dog searchterm2 @(cat, doggerel)
    @(cat, dog) searchterm1 @mouse searchterm2 
    @caterpillar"""

# scan for invalid terms, and print out the terms and their locations
for t,s,e in sphxTerm.scanString(test):
    print "Terms:%s Line: %d Col: %d" % (t, lineno(s, test), col(s, test))
    print line(s, test)
    print " "*(col(s,test)-1)+"^"
    print
```

With these lovely results:

```
Terms:['goat'] Line: 3 Col: 29
    @(cat, dog) search term @(goat)
                            ^

Terms:['doggerel'] Line: 4 Col: 39
    @cat searchterm1 @dog searchterm2 @(cat, doggerel)
                                      ^

Terms:['caterpillar'] Line: 6 Col: 5
    @caterpillar
    ^
```

This last snippet will do all the scanning for you, and just give you the list of found invalid tags:

```
# print out all of the found invalid terms
print list(set(sum(sphxTerm.searchString(test), ParseResults([]))))
```

Prints:

```
['caterpillar', 'goat', 'doggerel']
```

Comment: This looks an excellent (and much less hacky) way to do this. The method I described myself seems to work, but I'll put a comment in my code referencing this for future versions, since this looks more robust, elegant and explicit.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
@\((cat|dog|mouse|puppy)\b(,\s*(cat|dog|mouse|puppy)\b)*\)|@(cat|dog|mouse|puppy)\b
```

It will either match a single `@parameter` or a parenthesized `@(par1, par2)` list containing only allowed words (one or more).

It also makes sure that no partial matches are accepted (`@caterpillar`).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work though Tim. I get strange results with this, as if it's finding more hits than it should, and missing others.

Comment: Also, I should emphasize, I need to find the INVALID terms, not the valid ones.

Comment: Well, in RegexBuddy, it matches all the terms in your examples and none of the invalid terms. Can you give an example where it's not doing what is expected?

Answer (score 0):

This will match all fields that are cat, dog, mouse, or puppy and combinations thereof.

```
import re
sphinx_term = "@goat some words to search"
regex = re.compile("@\(?(cat|dog|mouse|puppy)(, ?(cat|dog|mouse|puppy))*\)? ")
if regex.search(sphinx_term):
    send the query to sphinx...
```

Comment: But that will miss the ones that have multiple fields. This is very similar to my first approach.

@(cat, goat) will be missed though.

Comment: Added in `(, ?(cat|dog|mouse|puppy))*` which will match fields separated by ','

Comment: Hmmm...still getting weird results. My test data is of the form: @foo @Dog @caterpillar @mouse foo,bar @(Dog, caterpillar, mice) @(bar, mouse) @(mouse) (cat | dog

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
field_re = re.compile(r"@(?:([^()\s]+)|\([^()]+\))")
```

A single field name (like `cat` in `@cat`) will be captured in group #1, while the names in a parenthesized list like `@(cat, dog)` will be stored in group #2.  In the latter case you'll need to break the list down with `split()` or something; there's no way to capture the names individually with a Python regex.